# String and Object response handling in same call Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, gson

I am using retrofit 2.3.0 for network in Android app.
I get response of say Person object I deserialize it using GsonConverter.
But sometime server sends normal String rather than json object then I get JsonSyntaxException because deserialzer expects json object rather than String. String comes only when server times out so rather than getting exception I want to show "time out".

How to handle these situations when server returns plain string rather than Object with Retrofit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generic `Object` in response and after you get the response, check if that matches either `String` or `JSON`. This method should work well i suppose.

Check out these answer for more details :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40131471/9809880

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35634754/9809880

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37663405/9809880